# Minima and Partial Derivatives

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

I am dealing with an equation that has two variables *x* and *t*. I have the following equation for the first order partial derivative with respect to *x*:

$\frac{\delta A}{\delta x} = \frac{2t - 3t^2}{2xt - 3xt^2}$.

Setting this equal to 0, I got a value for *t*. I can see it has 2 roots. Now, I wanted to check if any of these *t* achieves maxima or minima. When I compute the second derivative, I get the following:

$\frac{\delta^2 A}{\delta^2 x} = (-1) \frac{(2t - 3t^2)^2}{(2xt - 3xt^2)^2}$

This term is always negative. So, does it mean that this *t* value never achieves the minima? Or should I do $\frac{\delta^2 A}{\delta x \delta t}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ depends on both $x$ and $t$, the extrema are found first by setting $\frac{\partial A}{\partial x} = 0$ AND $\frac{\partial A}{\partial t} = 0$. Both of these equations must be satisfied for a point $(a,b)$ to be an extrema.

To check if this point you found is a max or min, you want to compute the Hessian $$H(a,b) = A_{xx}(a,b)A_{tt}(a,b) - 2A_{xt}(a,b)$$ at $(a,b)$. If $H(a,b)>0$, then $(a,b)$ is a relative maximum if $A_{xx}(a,b)<0$, or a minimum if $A_{xx}(a,b) >0$. If $H(a,b) < 0$, $(a,b)$ is a saddle point.